# How to redirect stderr for subprocess module

Tags: python, python-2.4

Based on the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978101/python-subprocess-popen-wait-returns-0-even-though-an-error-occured), I wanted to save the error as a string:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ding', 'dong'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
```

However, it seems that redirecting stderr is not working:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['ding', 'dong'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 993, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is the correct way to capture the error as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message in the question does not come from the subprocess. It was generated before the subprocess execution. You cannot capture that error using `stderr` option.

Make sure there's `ding` program in the path.